# Getting empty when using my own strcopy function

Tags: c, strcpy

```
void strcopy(char *src, char *dst) {
  int len = strlen(src) - 1;
  dst = (char*)malloc(len);
  while(*src){
    *dst = *src;
     src++; dst++;
  }
  *dst = '\0';
}
int main() {
  char *src = "hello";
  char *dst = "";
  strcopy(src, dst);
  printf("strcpy:%s\n", dst);
  return 0;
}

Output:
strcpy:
```

Can anyone please explain what's wrong in my strcopy function? But I am getting the output as correct if do `malloc` in `main`. Confused, as malloc allocates memory in heap only right?

Comment: It is better to leave the memory allocation to the caller. A properly designed string copy function should only concern itself with its designated task: copying strings.

Answer (score 6):

In your case,

```
  strcopy(src, dst);
```

`dst` itself is passed by value. You cannot allocate memory inside your function and expect the same to be *reflected* in caller function.

If you want memory to be allocated to `dst` inside `strcopy()`, you need to either

- pass a pointer to `dst`.
- or you can also `return` the newly allocated `dst` from your function and collect the same back into `dst` in the caller.

  *However, please bear in mind, as you're allocating the memory yourself, it is your duty to `free()` it.*

Otherwise, you can allocate memory to `dst` inside your caller (`main()`) function and then pass the already-allocated `dst` to your function to perform the copying job. IMHO, this approach has more resemblance to the library function `strcpy()` as the API itself does not handle the allocation of memory for the destination.

---

Note:: That said, in the code

```
 int len = strlen(src) - 1;
```

you're facing a logical error. It should rather be

```
 int len = strlen(src) + 1;
```

to accumulate the terminating null, also.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few problems there:

1. When you do this in your `strcopy`:

   ```
   dst = (char*)malloc(len);
   ```

   you're *overwriting* the pointer in the `dst` argument with a new pointer. This has no effect *at all* on the `dst` variable in main, because its *value*, not a reference to it, was passed into `strcopy`. So naturally when you print out the string that `main`'s `dst` points to, it's unchanged, and still `""`.
2. You're not allocating enough memory for the copy. You've done:

   ```
   int len = strlen(src) - 1;
   dst = (char*)malloc(len);
   ```

   which allocates **two bytes too little**. You need `+ 1`, not `- 1`: The number of characters in the source string (`strlen(src)`) **plus** one for the terminating null character.
3. You're allocating memory you never release.

   **Remember, it was written thus:**

   > ***As Ye `malloc`, so shall Thee `free`***

#2 is easily fixed by using `+ 1` instead of `- 1`.

#1 is fixed in any number of ways:

1. You could have your `strcopy` allocate the memory for the copy, then don't pass `dst` in, and have it return the pointer it allocated. Its documentation would say that it did an allocation the caller is expected to deallocate. E.g.:

   ```
   char * strcopy(char *src) {
     int len = strlen(src) + 1;
     char * dst = (char*)malloc(len);
     for (p = dst; *src; ++p, ++src) {
       *p = *src;
     }
     *p = '\0';
     return dst;
   }
   int main() {
     char *src = "hello";
     char *dst = strcopy(src);
     printf("strcopy:%s\n", dst);
     free(dst);                      // <== note
     return 0;
   }
   ```
2. You could write to the memory `main`'s `dst` points to, but you'd need to be sure that you allocate enough. Typically in C if you're passing a buffer into a function that should write to the buffer, you also pass the size of the buffer so the function knows where to stop.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong in your code.

Firstly, your `strcopy()` function allocates `strlen(src) - 1` characters to `dst`, and then copies `strlen(src) + 1` characters to it.   That gives undefined behaviour.

Second, your `main()` passes its local `dst` by value (i.e. the address of the first character in the string literal `""`.   Changing the value of `dst` in `strcopy()` therefore has no effect on the value of `dst` in `main()`.  The fact that the two variables (in `main()` and in `strcopy()`) have the same name does not change that.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the comments and proposals of others, your code could be as follows:

```
void strcopy(char *src, char **_dst) {
  int len = strlen(src) + 1;
  char *dst = malloc(len);
  *_dst= dst;
  while(*src){
    *dst = *src;
     src++; dst++;
  }
  *dst = '\0';
}
int main() {
  char *src = "hello";
  char *dst;
  strcopy(src, &dst);
  printf("strcpy:%s\n", dst);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
void strcopy(char **src, char **dst) {
  int len = strlen(*src) + 1;
  *dst = (char*)malloc(len);
  int j;
  for(j=0;j<strlen(*src);j++)
  {
    dst[j] = src[j];
  }
  dst[j] = '\0';
}

int main() {
  char *src = "hello";
  char *dst = "";

  strcopy(&src, &dst);
  printf("strcpy:%s\n", dst);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function parameters are local variables of the function. A function deals with copies of its arguments. So any changes of a parameter within the function do not influence on the original value of the corresponding argument.

So for example this statement in function `strcopy`

```
dst = (char*)malloc(len);
```

does not change the argument `dst` defined in main.

```
char *dst = "";
```

If you want to write indeed a function named like `strcopy` when the function should deal with already allocted arrays. Otherwise the function should be named like for example `strdup`  if it itself creates a new copy of the source string.

Moreover your function  is wrong because it can try to allocate a memory with a negative memory size when the source string is empty and therefore `strlen(src)` is equal to 0. And in any case it allocates less memory than it is required.

```
int len = strlen(src) - 1;
dst = (char*)malloc(len);
```

The function can be defined the following way

```
char * strcopy( char *dst, const char *src ) 
{
    char *p = dst;

    while ( ( *p++ = *src++ ) );

    return dst;
}
```

and called like

```
int main( void ) 
{
    char *src = "hello";
    char dst[6];

    printf( "strcpy:%s\n", strcopy( dst, src ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Take also into account that you may not change string literals in C (and C++). Any attempt vto change a string literal results in undefined behaviour of the program.

Thus you may not declare variable `dst` like for example

```
char *dst = "A string literal";
```

and call function `strcopy` passing `dst` as the first argument in the above program.

If you want to create a copy of a source string then the function can be defined the following way

```
char * strdup( const char *src ) 
{
    char *dst = malloc( ( strlen( src ) + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );

    if ( dst )
    {
        char *p = dst;
        while ( ( *p++ = *src++ ) );
    }

    return dst;
}
```

and called like

```
int main( void ) 
{
    char *src = "hello";
    char *dst;

    dst = strdup( src ) ;
    printf( "strcpy:%s\n", dst );

    free( dst );

    return 0;
}
```